# Javascript: How to inject javascript at user's side

Tags: javascript

I have a myCode.js file. i want that file to be remained in users computer for specific time or till the user clears it manualy.

In current case, i m including file as:

```
<script src='js/myCode.js'></script>
```

But the file is loaded each time user request the page. How can i make this file to stay at user's computer so that it wont get re-downloaded on each page.

Comment: normally, external resources are cached by the browser. Check the response code on page reload for 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the myCode.js file to myCode.php file and added a code at the start.

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
  $ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 1) . " GMT";
  header($ExpStr);
?>
```

and then include that file to webpages

```
<script src='js/myCode.php'></script>
```

In above code i dont know where its getting wrong

Comment: You have to add more than 1 second. Now you code expires after 1 second. You can make it stay there for 1 day doing adding something like this: header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+24*60*60) . ' GMT'); You can easily make it even more permanent, and later load js / css files using pattern <script src='js/myCode.php?ver=NUMBER_HERE'></script> If browser see new number, it will consider file as new one and download it. This file will expires after 1 day (in my example).

Answer (score 5):

You can't make it "stay" at users computer, but you can configure your apache server, to send headers that will say user browser, that this file hasn't changed and it can use file from temp.

Read more here: [Apache mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html), and you can read about ETags as well.

Comment: What you're really interested in is making it so that the user's browser can cache it, as in the above. If you're just serving it as a static file then your webserver will probably take care of that for you.